# Export all data under Azure policy exemptions

Tags: azure, azure-policy

As captioned, how can I export the whole view under Azure policy exemptions? Is there cli, powershell, or resource graph explorer that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what piece of information you would like to retrieve, but there is indeed CLI commands for that.

See [az policy exemption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/policy/exemption?view=azure-cli-latest#az-policy-exemption-list) - basically you can use `az policy exemption list` or `az policy exemption show`.

Or using Powershell - [Get-AzPolicyExemption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azpolicyexemption?view=azps-7.3.0).